# why does the dollar sign cause this command to be executed?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, variable-substitution, variable, subshell

test_script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
D1="$(dirname $0)"
echo $D1
D0="(dirname $0)"
echo $D0
```

What I type on the command line:

```
$ ./test_script.sh
```

Output:

```
.
(dirname ./test_script.sh)
```

What significance does the first dollar sign in D1's value have s.t. the command gets executed while D0's value is interpreted as a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A trivial search for `$(` in the shell man page gives the answer.

As `$name` causes parameter expansion `$(command)` causes command substitution i.e. it is replaced by the output of the command (with trailing newline(s) removed). `$(command)` causes word splitting after the expansion, `"$(command)"` avoids it (like `$name` vs. `"$name"`).

`"(dirname)"` on the other hand is just a literal string to the shell.